# PlaceAutoComplete not transalating accurately into an address

Tags: android, google-places-api, reverse-geocoding

I have a PlaceAutoComplete via which I choose the first result in the below screenshot:

[image]

Then I translate it into an address via the following code:

```
  Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(endLocation.getLatLng().latitude, endLocation.getLatLng().longitude, 1);

        if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {

            // TODO -=- Destination city check

            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
            }

            // Update screen with Location
                endLocationOnScreen.setText(sb.toString());


        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

See the results on screen:

[image]

The address is translated badly -- fair enough you may think. But in some cases, there is a huge difference.

For example, searching for "L&T South City Apartments" (in Bangalore) shows the address as 8B Cross Road, Arekere in AutoPlaceComplete, but resulting transation is "270, 8B Cross Road, Santrupthi Nagar, JP Nagar" - a few streets away.

The problem isn't much in terms of accuracy, but in terms of user experience. They see something else from what they selected on the screen.

How do I overcome this? Is there any way to get what is shown on AutoComplete onto the screen to show back to user?

Answer (score 0):

PlaceAutoComplete api returns a placeid for every place. You can use this placeid to get accurate place detail using google api below

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details
```